# Refresh SQLite list after adding new in a different activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two activities - one displays data from [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite), and the other adds data there. I can switch between them with tabs. The problem is that if I add a new item I don't know how to refresh the list, because it's in a different activity class and I can't access it in my adding class. How can this be solved?

Here is my two classes:

List:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

    final ShoppingSQL shoppingSQL = new ShoppingSQL(this);
    final List<ShoppingData> list = shoppingSQL.getAll();

    final ArrayAdapter<ShoppingData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ShoppingData>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
       this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                shoppingSQL.delete((int)list.get(position).getId());
                adapter.remove(list.get(position));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

Add:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
}

public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {
    ShoppingSQL shoppingSQL = new ShoppingSQL(this);

    ShoppingData data = new ShoppingData();
    data.setName("test");

    shoppingSQL.add(data);

    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("Added!");
    d.show();
}
```

I also have a little sidequestion. In my first (list) activity, [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) made every variable final when I accessed them in "onLongClick" - why is that and can that be avoided? Also any comment on what I should look in to as well and make my code better or any other mistakes I made would be very good.

Comment: use cursor.setNotificationUri, contentResolver.notifyChange, and maybe cursor.registerContentChangeObserver

Comment: you need your variable either final or in a broader scope when accessing from an anonymous class. Typically, you could have those instance members. Or, you could notice that id is provided as a parameter (no need to get(position).getId, and that the adapter is passed too. You can cast it to avoid having to refer to the other reference.

Comment: Have the Add activity trigger an event and make the other pick up this euent and refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd keep it simple. Just send an intent from Add class to List class and then your list will be populated again with new items.

Comment: I put this in add:
Intent i = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
and it worked. Sent my back to list and loaded everything again. Thanks! :)

Comment: Use at least the local BroadcastManager. Otherwise, you generate much overhead due to inter process communication.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("de.vogella.android.mybroadcast");
sendBroadcast(intent); 

Like this?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is a CursorLoader that is connected to your SQLite DB (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html). Then, you can use, e.g., a ListView whose adapter synchronizes with the CursorLoader. This is done (more or less) automatically using the listener pattern.

In the activity that adds the data, you then need to notify all listeners that the data has changed. Typically, you do this by calling **notifyChange** (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver,%20boolean%29).

You might also want to think about implementing your own content provider.

Comment: Thank you also. I must admint i didnt understand much of what you said and soulreaver's anwser was more simple for me but still thanks alot for the effort. Ill read it again when im better at java/android and im sure it will hep me :)

Comment: CursorLoaders are Andoids standard patterns used to listen for changes in an underlaying data source. For a nice and clear code, you should read some tutorials about this topic. It really helped me understand what's going on.